# Possible size = 1 complex numbers that when divided by their conjugate, produce a size = 1 number

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing

Let’s assume we have a complex number $z$ that $|z| =1$.

How many different complex numbers like $a$ exist, when $|a| = 1$ and $$z = \frac{a}{\bar{a}}$$? How could we prove that?

Comment: Since $|a|=1$, $\frac a{\bar a}=a^2$. You are basically asking how many $a$ exist such that $z=a^2$. That would be 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use exponential notation: $$z=e^{i\xi}\\a=e^{i\phi}$$ Then $$\bar a=e^{-i\phi}$$ and $$z=e^{2i\phi}=e^{i\xi}$$
The obvious solution is $\phi=\frac{\xi}2$, but you need to account for the periodicity:$$e^{2i\phi}=e^{2i\phi+i2\pi}$$
So assuming that $\xi$ is in the interval $[0,2\pi)$, then $\phi=\frac{\xi}2$ is in the interval $[0,\pi)$. Then you have the other solution $\frac{\xi}2+\pi$ in the interval $[\pi,2\pi)$